# how to implement Ionic-react offline mode

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, native, offline, ionic-react

[image: webpage not available]

I want to make a ionic app offline but i don't know how to implement

Comment: Watch your `index.tsx`, you have to register your [service worker](https://cra.link/PWA).

Comment: What does your app connect to the Internet for?  Ionic doesn't need an Internet connection out of the box; that's something you add yourself as you develop the app.

Answer (score 0):

Adding offline support to an existing app can be straightforward when you start with the basics. By utilizing the [Ionic Native SQLite module](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite)

You can check this article for more details [here](https://ionicframework.com/blog/building-an-ionic-app-with-offline-support-part-1/).